# How do I make my vector grow to initially unknown size?

Tags: c++

How do I continue this vector forever till it ends? I'm not sure because all my attempts were reacted with errors.

Can someone give me an example how to do it correctly? I've tried to google it, but didn't really find any answer

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(10); 

    for (int v = 0; v < a.size(); v++ ){
        
            std::cin >> a[v];
            if (a[v] == -1) {
                break;
            }
            
    }
    int x;
    for (int x = 0; x != -1;) {
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cin >> x;
        bool exists = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), x) != std::end(a);
        if (exists == 1) {
            std::cout << "found" << " ";
        }
        else if (exists == 0) {
            std::cout << "not found" << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of pushback? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back Please have a look and explain why it does not allow you to achieve your goal.

Comment: nope I'm a beginner, it worked, thanks

Comment: I create an answer then.

Comment: This doesn't addres the question, but `if (exists == 1) ... else if (exists == 0) ...` should be written `if (exists) ... else ...`. The type of `exits` is `bool`, so it can hold two values: `true` and `false`. So `if (exists) ...` will execute if the value in `exists` is `true`, and the `else` branch will execute if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

You do it by establishing an initially empty vector then using `push_back` or `emplace_back` members to append properly-received user input to the vector. In short, your code would end up looking like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    int  x;

    while (std::cin >> x && x != -1)
        a.emplace_back(x);

    while (std::cin >> x && x != -1)
    {
        if (std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), x) != std::end(a))
            std::cout << "found\n";
        else
            std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pushback features of std::vector will allow you to achieve your goal.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

In short, using it looks like:

```cpp
a.push_back(myIntvariable);
```

Fill the variable from input beforehand.